# how to construct a json object using info from several javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two js arrays already, say: names and values (with the same length), now I would like to construct a json object in certain format? For example:

```
 names = ["label1","label2","label3"];
 values = [[[0,1],[1,9],[2,10]],[[0,89],[1,91],[2,1]],[[0,1],[1,9],[2,10]]];
```

I would like to have a json array `data_spec` in this format:

```
 [{
    label:"label1",
    data:[[0,1],[1,9],[2,10]]
  },
  {
    label:"label2",
    data:[[0,89],[1,91],[2,1]]
  },
  {
    label:"label3",
    data:[[0,1],[1,9],[2,10]]
  }]
```

Could anyone tell one how? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a loop (make sure the two arrays are of same length)

```
result = [];
for(var i=0, len=names.length; i < len; i++) {
    result.push({label: names[i], data: values[i]});
}
```

Comment: @Chetan, please optimize your for loop by calculating **names.length** outside of the loop and I'll give you +1

Comment: Done, but is Array#length expensive enough to bother? I know nodelist#length is.

Comment: I can't say for sure which is more costly, but the optimization alone reduces the calls to **names.length** by N where N is the number of array items (which *could* be very costly)

Comment: I prefer something like `for (var i=0; names[i]; i++) {}` for situations like this, when you know names[i] would never be 0, false, null, undefined or a blank string :-)

Comment: array.length isn't a call it's a property of the object. there's no optimization to be found changing this code .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208320/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-array-length

Comment: @Scott: I ran a few benchmarks and only IE seemed to run marginally slower (about 4%) when array.length was accessed repeatedly. Now the linked question is for java which is JIT'ed and is not a dynamic language. But in this case, I do agree that it's rather a premature optimization and is not worth the cost of reduced readability.

Answer (score 6):

For a bit of variety and a check,

```
var data_spec = [];
if (names.length != values.length) {
    // panic, throw an exception, log an error or just return an empty array
} else {
    for (var i=0, name; name = names[i]; i++) { // assuming a non-sparse array
        data_spec[i] = { 
            label : name, 
            data  : values[i] 
        };
    }
}
```

That is, *non-sparse* and not containing anything else that would evaluate to *false*.

If your framework has an *each* function added to Array and you don't care about performance,

```
var data_spec = [];
names.each(function(name) {
    data_spec.push({ label : name, data : values[names.indexOf(name)] });
});
```

If your framework is a clean one like Dojo and puts it somewhere else (ex is Dojo),

```
var data_spec = [];
dojo.forEach(names, function(name) {
    data_spec.push({ label : name, data : values[names.indexOf(name)] });
});
```

If your framework has an *each* function that returns an Array of identical length with the results of every operation at their expected position,

```
var data_spec = arrayOfResultsEach(names, function(name) {
    return { label : name, data : values[names.indexOf(name)] };
});
```

These are just for illustration, *indexOf* inside loops of arbitrary length is a major code smell.

Comment: Most array iterator implementations (prototype, jQuery.each) also pass the `index` parameter to the iterator function. So you don't need the `indexOf`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    var myArray = 
    [{
        "label": "label1",
        "data" : 
        {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "9",
            "2": "10"
        }
    },

    {
        "label": "label2",
        "data" : 
        {
            "0": "89",
            "1": "91",
            "2": "1"
        }
    },

    {
        "label": "label3",
        "data" : 
        {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "9",
            "2": "10"
        }
    }];

    alert(myArray[0].data[2]);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the asker is looking for a dynamic implementation /sarcasm.  Also, why use object literals for "data" instead of arrays?