# Simple loop performance issue

Tags: java, php, performance

Say I have a simple PHP loop like this one

```
// Bad example
$array = array('apple','banana','cucumber');
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

I know this is a bad practice. It's better **not** using `count()` inside a loop.

```
// Nice example
$array = array('apple','banana','cucumber');
$limit = count($array);
for ($i = 1; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    // do something...
}
```

In Java, I would do it this way

```
// Bad example?
String[] array = {"apple","banana","cucumber"};
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

**Question:** Isn't this above a bad practice too? Or it is just the same as the example below?

```
// Nice example?
String[] array = {"apple","banana","cucumber"};
int limit = array.length;
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Cost of Calling array.length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208320/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-array-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "bad" examples you use are not equivalent, and thus are not comparable - even if they seem so on the surface. Using this description:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

(which is descriptive of both PHP and java loops), the *initialization* statement is executed once, at the start of the loop. The *termination* statement and the *increment* are executed for each iteration of the loop.

The reason it is bad practice to use PHP's `count` in the *termination* statement is that, for each iteration, the `count` function call occurs. In your Java example, `array.length` is not a function call but a reference to a public member. Therefore, the *termination* statements used in your examples are not equivalent behavior. We *expect* a function call to be more costly than a property reference.

It is bad practice to place a function call (or call a property that masks a function) in the *termination* statement of a for loop in **any language** which has the described loop mechanics. That's what makes the PHP example "bad", and it would be equally bad if you used a `count`-type function in Java for loop's termination statement. The real question, then, is whether Java's `Array.length` does indeed mask a function call - the answer to that is "no" (see the potential duplicate question, and/or check out http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks Chris! In fact, my doubt was that `Array.length` could be a method - I was confusing with `String.length()`, that *is* a method. `Array.length` is just a property. So my Java "bad example" isn't really bad.

Answer (score 6):

Any decent compiler/interpreter should automatically optimise the first example to match the second (semantically speaking anyway, if not exactly literally), and probably the third to match the fourth. It's known as a *loop invariant optimisation*, where the compiler recognises that an entity (variable, expression, etc) does not vary within the loop (i.e. is *invariant*) and removes it to outside the loop (loosely speaking).

It's not bad practice at all anymore, if it ever was.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but it is interresting. However: +1.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Thanks for upvoting! IIRC, the question was "is this bad practice"? I specifically addressed that in my second paragraph (no, it isn't bad practice) and the rest of my answer explains why. It also explains why the third example is essentially the same as the fourth (which was the other question).

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `count()` is a function whereas `array.length` is a property and therefore not different from a `limit` variable.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, in the Java "nice example" you are not calculating the length of the array every time. Instead, you are storing that in the limit variable and using that to stop the calculation instead of the result of calling the length function on the array every iteration through the for loop.

EDIT: Both of the things that you thought were "bad practice" are bad practice and the "nice examples" are the more efficient ways (at least in theory).  But it is true that in implementation there will not be any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

In java this doesn't matter an array has this attribute as a constant (public final int).
The difference is in java arrays have a fixed size and can not grow so there would be no need to count the elements every time to access length.