# Array Length in Java - Performance

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I create an array of ints with length 10, i.e.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

At some point in my code, I want to compare the value of an int variable, let's call it var, with the length of the array.

I would like to know if this piece of code:

```
if(var == array.length) { // stuff }
```

and this piece of code:

```
if(var == 10) { // stuff }
```

which do exactly the same thing, have also the same performance.

In other words, I would like to know the internal mechanics that the JVM (?) uses to find the length of the array (I don't say "to return" since length is a field, not a method). Does it make use of iteration? Because if it does, then the 2nd piece of code would be faster than the 1st one.

EDIT: Similar question regarding array.length cost (even though focusing more to its use in for loops):

[What is the Cost of Calling array.length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208320/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-array-length)

Comment: Never use the second one. Always use the first one. [Magic numbers are bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

Comment: The (JIT) compiler will optimze this out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In general you are right about that, but in my code this is not a problem,  really. From a performance point of view?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but logic dictates that the field is updated when the array langth changes (;)). thus, a lookup for the array length doesn't need any iteration, for the field already contains the number.

Comment: @CoolBeans     I haven't check this because it is about 2-D array (i.e. a table). I will take a look, maybe I will find something there.

Comment: @VivinPaliath  Ooops, yes, you are right, this question address the same issue! I will edit my question and put a link for that post.

Answer (score 3):

`.length` is a property, so it would not do iteration for sure. Still, the value of the property is, naturally, fetched at runtime, meaning that the second solution will be a little bit faster (as this is comparison with constant).

Still the first implementation is far more preferable:

- This makes your code quite more maintainable
- You can alter the length of the array only at one place
- You will never feel the performance difference unless you pass through this if litterally millions of times in a second.

**EDIT** By the way you can yourself tell this is a property - there are no braces after the call. I at least do not know of a way in java to make property access do additional computation, but just retrieving its value.

Comment: +1 for the good answer, it highlights all the aspects of the concept! Thank you!

Comment: @PeterHiggs Sure, thanks. Also please mind my edit I think it will help you get around similar cases in the future.

Comment: Yes I will! I am new in programming and it happens from time to time to have questions that are simple to answer and have to do with fundamental concepts, but at least once I learn from my mistakes, I usually don't repeat them! :)

Answer (score 1):

`.length` is a property of the array, not a function. Thus, the result would be available immediately, with no iteration necessary.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I wanted to be sure, because I have some code that runs much slower than expected and I want to find out why! Well, array.length is not the problem apparently! Thank you!

Comment: @PeterHiggs any chance the Java chat room would like to help?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    Yes, I think I will discuss about my performance issues and how to optimize the performance of my code on the Java chat.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    Already uploaded on the chat, you could take a look if you would like: https://filetea.me/t1sLLgTRgRbTGizbpbc5e1EYQ and https://filetea.me/t1seyU1k5P7Q5qxx1JMP9iKTg

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

The members of an array type are all of the following:

> The **public final field length**, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.

length is an final **field** of array, so no iterations are required while writing following code.

```
if(var == array.length) { // stuff }
```

And it is good coding practice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The length property of an array is extracted in constant (O(1)) time - there is no iteration needed. It's also good practice to use this.