# Calling size() in a for loop condition, bad efficiency?

Tags: java

I just wanted to know in general, is this code inefficient:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    //do something
}
```

as opposed to:

```
int x = array.size(); 

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

or is it negligible? (How about in nested for loops?)

Comment: Are you programming a business application or a rocket chip? Probably it matters only for the latter one :)

Comment: It's negligible.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Similar,but for arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1208331/3040381

Comment: Doesnt the compiler optimize this to eventually the same code. Asking.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `array` is an `ArrayList`, it's of almost no difference since the implementation of `size()` merely accesses a member field:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

The second code just saves the field value in a local variable and re-uses it in the loop instead of accessing the field every time, so that's just a difference between an access to a local variable versus an access to a field (accessing a local variable is slightly faster).

Answer (score 1):

You can test it yourself doing some test like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Long> array = new ArrayList<Long>(99999);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 99999) {
        array.add(1L);
        i++;
    }
    long ini1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
        i += array.get(j);
    }
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time1: " + (end1 - ini1));
    long ini2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 99999; j++) {
        i += array.get(j);
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time2: " + (end2 - ini2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Time1: 13
Time2: 10
```

I think that the difference its irrelevant in most applications and cases, i run the test several times and the times vary but the difference keeps "constant" at least in terms of percentage...

Comment: I think that the second loop should use a local variable not the literal `99999` in order to exactly replicate the OP's case. But that should not really make a difference...

Comment: @manouti yeah, you are right, but i test both cases and the result are pretty similar, i choose this to reduce some code ;).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have a size, but length

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

Efficiency is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

actually, performance is almost the same if array.size is not very big.
u can always make like this:

```
for (int i = 0, x = array.length; i < x; i++) {
    //do something
}
```