# How to improve performance of code from 60%

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am solving a simple problem on one of the coding challenge websites where I need to find the missing element from the array.

Problem statement is that you have `an input array from 1 to N+1 and you have to find the missing element from that array.`

```
For example, given array A such that:

  A[0] = 2
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 5
the function should return 4, as it is the missing element.
```

For solving this I wrote a simple function that computed the result

```
def sol(a: Array[Int]): Int = {
  ((a.length+1)*(a.length+2)/2)-a.sum
}
```

However on submitting the solution I got the correctness of the solution as 100% but was shocked to see the performance results at 60%. Can anybody point out any part of this one line code that can be optimised or is there any other way to achieve 100% performance for this ?

Note : I am looking out for functional style code.

Comment: The problem here is - how is that website measuring performance ?

Comment: Unless the input array is not sorted all solutions are O(n). One downside of this solution is if N is too big you may end up with integer overflows. I don't think the problem is integer overflow, can you share the rest of the code? May be you are missing something there

Comment: Also, you're calling `a.length` twice. Call it once and store the result instead.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne; According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208320/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-array-length), there is little to no benefit in saving the `length` in a local variable.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's really strange. I submitted almost the same solution on codility and got 100%

Comment: @dyrkin how is that possible

Comment: I just ran your code on codility. And the error is not regarding performance but regarding the wrong answer `got -2147483647 expected 1`. To avoid integer overflow your sum must be of a Long type. To achieve this you can use `a.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)` instead of `a.sum`